# How do you access the activelines table for nested functions (Lua 5.1)?

Tags: lua, code-coverage

I want to be able to read a file, and return a list of all the lines of real code (not comments or whitespace), using the debugger's activelines table. However, it seems like if you have nested functions, the debugger fails to be able to provide the activelines for these nested functions, without an explicit call of the nested functions, and while running a hook. Is there a nice way to get back a list of all the active lines in a file without having to explicitly call all of the functions? Of course it would be lovely if you could do something like `debug.getinfo(file,"L").activelines` but that would be too easy...

I have a file that looks like the following:

```lua
return function()            -- A
  function f1()              -- B 
    f2(function()            -- C
      --function stuff goes here
      end)
  end
end
```

If I use debug.getlocal(2,i) and loop over all the locals in the function returned when executing the file (inside a hook) then I get access to the function f1, and when I call debug.getinfo(f1,"L").activelines, the table will contain lines B and C, but none of the lines inside the function which is an argument in f2. I need to get ALL of the active lines in the file, including ones which are inside functions like the one passed as an argument to f2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `luac` to display all active line numbers (in square brackets)

```
C:\>luac54 -l -p -
return function()  -- A
  function f1()    -- B
    f2(function()  -- C
      print"Hi"    -- D
       end)
  end
end
^Z

main <stdin:0,0> (4 instructions at 000001f3e84f7880)
0+ params, 2 slots, 1 upvalue, 0 locals, 0 constants, 1 function
        1       [1]     VARARGPREP      0
        2       [7]     CLOSURE         0 0     ; 000001f3e84f7a00
        3       [7]     RETURN          0 2 1   ; 1 out
        4       [7]     RETURN          0 1 1   ; 0 out

function <stdin:1,7> (3 instructions at 000001f3e84f7a00)
0 params, 2 slots, 1 upvalue, 0 locals, 1 constant, 1 function
        1       [6]     CLOSURE         0 0     ; 000001f3e84f7b50
        2       [2]     SETTABUP        0 0 0   ; _ENV "f1"
        3       [7]     RETURN0

function <stdin:2,6> (4 instructions at 000001f3e84f7b50)
0 params, 2 slots, 1 upvalue, 0 locals, 1 constant, 1 function
        1       [3]     GETTABUP        0 0 0   ; _ENV "f2"
        2       [5]     CLOSURE         1 0     ; 000001f3e84f7cc0
        3       [3]     CALL            0 2 1   ; 1 in 0 out
        4       [6]     RETURN0

function <stdin:3,5> (4 instructions at 000001f3e84f7cc0)
0 params, 2 slots, 1 upvalue, 0 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
        1       [4]     GETTABUP        0 0 0   ; _ENV "print"
        2       [4]     LOADK           1 1     ; "Hi"
        3       [4]     CALL            0 2 1   ; 1 in 0 out
        4       [5]     RETURN0
```

This example is for Luac 5.4, but Luac 5.1 will act the same way.

Comment: This does seem to work, but I actually need to write the code in Lua to do this generically for any file. This is just an example that breaks my current implementation.

Comment: Then you should parse bytecode in Lua.  The Lua bytecode format is open.

Comment: Would you mind providing some example Lua code for how one would go about parsing bytecode?

Comment: [Example of parsing Lua bytecode](https://github.com/lua-bytecode/lua-bytecode.github.io/blob/master/lua-bytecode.lua)

Comment: Oof a lot of work just to get a list of all the active lines in a file... sheesh. Thank you for the detailed answer.